# links to screenshots in TestNG's HTML reports

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a suite in offering direct tests when they do a screenshot of an error or exception. Pictures enroll in the directory test-output. How to do that in the report html directory Reporter-output there are links to them? Is it possible to associate them with specific errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your html report is in "test-output" directory and your screenshots are in "test-output/screenshots" directory, then:

```
(...)
String destDir = "test-output/screenshots";
String destFile = dateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".png";
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(destDir + "/" + destFile));
Reporter.log("<a href=/screenshots/" + destFile + "><img src=/screenshots/" + destFile + " style=width:100px;height:100px;/>" + destFile + "</a><br/>");
```

Comment: Thx.Little path : Reporter.log("<a href= screenshots/" + destFile + "><img src= screenshots/" + destFile + " style=width:100px;height:100px;/>" + destFile + "</a><br/>"); And works god.